# Using TreeNodeCollection, TreeNodeBinding, TreeView to add nodes for GridViews

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, treenodecollection

I am working on improving a business process, where the existing View state calls for GridView items, but now seeks to implement in a collapsing tree.  I have found the simplest method is to shadow the logic and during the aggregate stages assign tree nodes and add to the collection, preserving inheritance.  What I can't seem to find, is exactly how to pull the TreeNodeCollection and bind to the TreeView, whether it is a TreeNodeBinding per node, per tree, or something else.  I have seen some add text and XML, but this has to display GridView objects from VB.Net.

If it isn't obvious, I am new with VB but have a strong background in Java/PHP.  Please keep suggestions pertinent to the fact that I cannot redesign things completely(large project), and it has to work around what is there already.

Thanks!

Comment: You would be more likely to get answers if your show the TreeNodeCollection code you've already written, and explain what's not working right / what you don't understand.

Comment: I am sorry, I actually solved this a month later and forgot to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found other controls to work better, but without expanding placeholders and doing jQuery there does not exist currently a VB.Net extension to place data bound controls in a tree view.  A list View works better for the original question